# Windows batch scripting: Unable to copy files containing html tags to another file

Tags: windows, batch-file

As part of a project I need to add text to the middle of many files using batch scripting. I am able to add the text successfully, but after copying the files to a new location I noticed that the HTML tags are missing. I only have this problem in Windows Server 2012/2008; in Windows 7 the HTML tags remain intaact.

```
My Code snippet:
@echo off

set SrcFolder=C:\Users\emlfilessample
set DstFolder=C:\Users\output

FOR %%f in (%SrcFolder%*.eml) do (
 (FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ %%f"`) do (
  SETLOCAL EnabledDelayedExpansion
  set "var=%%a"
   set "var=!var:*:=!"
   if "!var:~0,10" == "x-globalre" (
   echo X-SUBTYPE=RETURES 
 )
 echo(!var!
 ENDLOCAL
)) >> "%DstFolder%\%%~nxf"
)
```

Below is my sample input file...

```html
 **Sample input eml:**
   Date Mon,20 mar 2017
   From:ALan@vc.com
   To:Weijie@vc.com
   Message-ID:<10091223>
    Subject:Symphony
   x-globalrelay-MsgType: XXXX
   x-StreamType:xxxx
   x-contentstartdate:XXX
 
   <html><body>  Message ID:sm9atRNTnMA=Yay1R0QgoH.............. </html>
```

After executing my script in Server 2012 I am able to successfully inject the required text in the middle, but as I said the HTML tags are missing:

```html
 **Sample input eml:**
   Date Mon,20 mar 2017
   From:ALan@vc.com
   To:Weijie@vc.com
   Message-ID:<10091223>
    Subject:Symphony
   X-SUBTYPE=RETURES
   x-globalrelay-MsgType: XXXX
   x-StreamType:xxxx
   x-contentstartdate:XXX
 
   <Yay1R0QgoH.............. </html>
```

As said I am able to generate the desired output by adding the text in the middle  in Windows 8 with the same script. I am not able to identify why it is giving different output(html tags are missing)in Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Hi can anyone help me with this...

Answer (score 2):

Rewritten slightly, explanation mostly in `rem` comments:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set SrcFolder=C:\Users\emlfilessample
set DstFolder=C:\Users\output

FOR %%f in (%SrcFolder%\*.eml) do (
  > "%DstFolder%\%%~nxf" ( 
    FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%%~f"') do (
      rem remove leading spaces from original line if any
      FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G in ("%%~b") do (
        set "var=%%~G"
        SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
          if "!var:~0,10!" == "x-globalre" (
            echo X-SUBTYPE=RETURES 
          )
        ENDLOCAL
      )
      rem output original line including all ! exclamation marks 
      rem                      AND all leading spaces if any
      echo(%%b
    )
  )
)
rem debugging output type "%DstFolder%\*.eml"
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some syntax errors in original source code (missing `!` in `"!var:~0,10"`, additional `d` in `enableDdelayedexpansion`), but I don't see a reason for this not working on 2012/2008.

Try with

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "SrcFolder=C:\Users\emlfilessample"
    set "DstFolder=C:\Users\output"

    for %%f in ("%SrcFolder%\*.eml") do (
        (
            FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%%~ff"') do (
                set "var=%%a"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    set "var=!var:*:=!"
                    if "!var:~0,10!" == "x-globalre" (
                        echo X-SUBTYPE=RETURES 
                    )
                    echo(!var!
                endlocal
            )
        ) > "%DstFolder%\%%~nxf"
    )
```

Note that the `if "!var:~0,10!" == "x-globalre" (` line does not take into account the presence of spaces at the start of the line (the same your original code does).

Comment: Thanks MC ND.....adding setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion had done the trick thanks for your valuable suggestion